# Can't change row height in Xcode 6 dynamic table

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode6

I have a UItableViewController and want the row height to adapt to the text in the UITextView. If I use this code in viewDidLoad it makes the height of the rows too small to hold the text:

```
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension   
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
```

The only way I can find to adjust the size is by changing the Table View Row Height in the StoryBoard. This changes every cell in the table view which is not what I want.

Does anyone have a suggestion about what I am missing?

Comment: If `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` isn't working correctly, that means your cell constraints aren't fully satisfied and so aren't rendered how you want.

Comment: As far as I know my constraints are correct. I have pinned top and bottom of the textview to the margins of the cell. The switch which is in the same cell is only pinned to the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my working code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        var text:String
        if indexPath.section > 0 {
            text = switchNameArray [indexPath.row]
        } else {
            text = viewDescription
        }
        return calculateHeight(text)
}

func calculateHeight (text:String) -> CGFloat {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
    {
        return CGFloat(count(text)+50) // iPad
    } else {
        return CGFloat(count(text)+30) // iPhone
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a override method to change the height for each row.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 50

}
```

You can also create and If-Else condition if you want to make it bigger or smaller. Just return a number

Comment: Following the advice of wherisleo and @caleb I have managed to get the cell heights to be approximately right. I'll include the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100 //Whatever fits your need for that cell
}
```

You can get the cell with tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) and make the height whatever you need it to be.

Comment: I don't want to have to calculate the size for each cell. Apart from anything else my app is Universal so it gets very complicated.

Comment: Height for cells will most likely be very similar, if not the same on all devices. A simple fix, since the constrains are somehow not letting it auto resize, is to just make the height slightly bigger than the textView height. Just return the cell's textView.height + 10 or whatever you want your padding to be.

Comment: Isn't the textView height a function of the cell height given that I have pinned the edges to it?

Comment: Right. Try not pinning the edges and just use whatever auto layout tells you to use. The AutomaticDimension will only change if the the textView is resizing according to the text inside. You can also check the heights by pressing the Debug View Hierarchy when running on the simulator.

Comment: Everything I have read so far says that the textView should be pinned to the margins of the cell. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to adapt to the size of your content
get the current tableView frame then adjust the height
depending on the height of the content.

```
var frame = CGRect(origin: tableView.frame.origin, size: tableView.frame.size)

frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
tableView.frame = frame
```

Comment: This would change the height of the entire view, OP wants to change the height of the table row.